# Why do some compounds without carbonyl group give positive 2,4-DNPH test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I was performing some experiments in Chemistry Lab today in which I had to find the functional groups present in a compound.

It being a very basic undergraduate course introducing us to the Chemistry lab, the functional groups were quite basic, and we just worked with mono-functional group compounds, including Carboxylic Acids, Amines, Aldehydes, Ketones and Phenols.

When performing the 24DNPH test on a white powdery substance (which I think had the carboxylic acid group), I got an yellowish-orange precipitate which was further characterized when I added dil. $\ce{HCl}$ to the test tube.

However, the sample gave negative Fehling's, Tollen's and Legal's tests (Legal's test is the sodium nitroprusside test).

Later, I even performed a test on another substance which gave positive primary amine test, as it gave me a scarlet dye in an azodye coupling reaction with $\beta$-naphthol. (This has stained my hand with reddish spots :D).

Point is, even this substance gave me a yellowish precipitate on adding 24DNPH, but it wasn't the normal orange/red precipitate which we see on reacting actual carbonyl compounds with 24DNPH.

This left me wondering, what compounds are these yellow precipitates that I had got?

I'd be very happy if someone can answer this as it is really intriguing me for a long time.

Comment: 2,4-DNP is a nucleophile so will react with other groups than  just carbonyls.

Comment: So the product formed may be R-CO-NH-NH-{2,4(Ph(NO2)2)}? (I know it's not really a proper formula writing form, but I'm just asking to know)

Comment: It could be. A species like that would likely be coloured. I can't quite see how it would form from the free acid without some kind of coupling agent present. It could be just the salt of the acid (2,4-DNP being basic). With respect to the second (amine positive) material, what was the process for the azo dye forming reaction?

Comment: @Waylander The azodye process involved adding a little bit of $\ce{NaNO2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ to the unknown substance placed in an ice bath, followed by the addition of β-naphthol